# How to add a self-defined unit-engine to arcanist

Tags: git, unit-testing, phabricator, arcanist

I'm using arc as the tool for code reviewing. The bin/arc is not in the git repo, but I wanna add a test engine in the git repo.
Thus I create directories test-engine, in the test-engine:

```
__phutil_library_init__.php
__phutil_library_map__.php,
src/PyEngine.php
```

the **phutil_library_init**.php:

```
    <?php

    phutil_register_library('PyEngine', __FILE__);

the __phutil_library_map__.php:

    phutil_register_library_map(array(
        '__library_version__' => 2,
        'class' =>
        array(
          'PyEngine' => 'src/PyEngine.php',
        ),
        'function' =>
        array(
        ),
        'xmap' =>
        array(
          'PyEngine' => 'ArcanistUnitTestEngine',
        ),
    ));
```

the .arcconfig:

```
{
    "phabricator.uri" : "blabla",
    "load" : [
      "test-engine"
    ],
    "unit.engine" : "PyEngine"
}
```

but when I run arc unit, it reports error:

```
 phutil_register_library_map(array(
      '__library_version__' => 2,
      'class' =>
      array(
        'PyEngine' => 'src/PyEngine.php',
      ),
      'function' =>
      array(
      ),
      'xmap' =>
      array(
        'PyEngine' => 'ArcanistUnitTestEngine',
      ),
    ));[2015-09-08 09:11:55] ERROR 8: Undefined index: PyEngine at [~/Documents/codes/arcanist/libphutil/src/moduleutils/PhutilBootloader.php:136]
    PyEngine(head=dev, ref.master=fc7de2baac4e, ref.dev=615bad5693e1), arcanist(head=master, ref.master=968f4ae5d73e), phutil(head=master, ref.master=55f554b618b9)
      #0 PhutilBootloader::getLibraryMap(string) called at [<phutil>/src/symbols/PhutilSymbolLoader.php:194]
      #1 PhutilSymbolLoader::selectAndLoadSymbols() called at [<phutil>/src/moduleutils/PhutilBootloader.php:78]
      #2 PhutilBootloader::registerLibrary(string, string) called at [<phutil>/src/moduleutils/core.php:4]
      #3 phutil_register_library(string, string) called at [<PyEngine>/__phutil_library_init__.php:3]
      #4 include_once(string) called at [<phutil>/src/moduleutils/PhutilBootloader.php:226]
      #5 PhutilBootloader::executeInclude(string) called at [<phutil>/src/moduleutils/PhutilBootloader.php:207]
      #6 PhutilBootloader::loadLibrary(string) called at [<phutil>/src/moduleutils/core.php:12]
      #7 phutil_load_library(string) called at [<arcanist>/scripts/arcanist.php:611]
      #8 arcanist_load_libraries(array, boolean, string, ArcanistWorkingCopyIdentity) called at [<arcanist>/scripts/arcanist.php:162]
    phutil_register_library_map(array(
      '__library_version__' => 2,
      'class' =>
      array(
        'PyEngine' => 'src/PyEngine.php',
      ),
      'function' =>
      array(
      ),
      'xmap' =>
      array(
        'PyEngine' => 'ArcanistUnitTestEngine',
      ),
    ));[2015-09-08 09:11:55] ERROR 8: Undefined index: PyEngine at [~/Documents/codes/arcanist/libphutil/src/moduleutils/PhutilBootloader.php:136]
    PyEngine(head=dev, ref.master=fc7de2baac4e, ref.dev=615bad5693e1), arcanist(head=master, ref.master=968f4ae5d73e), phutil(head=master, ref.master=55f554b618b9)
      #0 PhutilBootloader::getLibraryMap(string) called at [<phutil>/src/symbols/PhutilSymbolLoader.php:194]
      #1 PhutilSymbolLoader::selectAndLoadSymbols() called at [<phutil>/src/__phutil_library_init__.php:22]
      #2 __phutil_autoload(string)
      #3 spl_autoload_call(string)
      #4 call_user_func_array(array, array) called at [<phutil>/src/console/format.php:7]
      #5 phutil_console_format(string, string) called at [<arcanist>/scripts/arcanist.php:413]
    [2015-09-08 09:11:55] EXCEPTION: (Exception) libphutil v1 libraries are no longer supported. at [<phutil>/src/moduleutils/PhutilBootloader.php:144]
    PyEngine(head=dev, ref.master=fc7de2baac4e, ref.dev=615bad5693e1), arcanist(head=master, ref.master=968f4ae5d73e), phutil(head=master, ref.master=55f554b618b9)
      #0 PhutilBootloader::getLibraryMap(string) called at [<phutil>/src/symbols/PhutilSymbolLoader.php:194]
      #1 PhutilSymbolLoader::selectAndLoadSymbols() called at [<phutil>/src/__phutil_library_init__.php:22]
      #2 __phutil_autoload(string)
      #3 spl_autoload_call(string)
      #4 call_user_func_array(array, array) called at [<phutil>/src/console/format.php:7]
      #5 phutil_console_format(string, string) called at [<arcanist>/scripts/arcanist.php:413]
```

How can I add the unit engine properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you ran `arc liberate` again after adding your class (and was it used to actually create your lib in the first place)?

You can get a little info (this is not officially supported yet) here:
https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabcontrib/article/adding_new_classes/